# The same C code behave in different ways when I change compiling optimizations

Tags: c

As an exercise I was trying to implement merge sort algorithm. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int *array) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void merge(int *array, int *temp, int left, int mid, int right) {
  int i=left, j=mid, k=left;
  while (i<mid && j<right) {
    if (array[i] > array[j]) {
      temp[k++]=array[j++];
    } else {
      temp[k++]=array[i++];
    }
  }
  while (i<mid) {
    temp[k++]=array[i++];
  }
  while (j<right) {
    temp[k++]=array[j++];
  }
  for (i=left; i<right; i++) {
    array[i]=temp[i];
  }
}

void mergeSort(int *array, int size) {
  int temp[size];
  int i,j;
  for (j=1; j<=size; j*=2) {
    printf("\n%d\n",j);
    for (i=0; i<size; i+=2*j) {
      if (i+2*j<size) {
        merge(array,temp, i, i+j, i+2*j);
      } else {
        merge(array,temp, i, i+j, size);
      }
    }
  }
}

int main() {
    int array[] = {83,86,77,15,93,35,86,92,49,21,62,27,90,59,63,26,40,26,72,36};
    printArray(array);
    mergeSort(array, 20);
    printArray(array);
}
```

Inside `mergeSort` I expected the iteration over `j` to stop for `f` equal to 16, since `size` is equal to 20, but in reality it goes up to 8; in fact the list is not completely ordered. This is the output:

```
83 86 77 15 93 35 86 92 49 21 62 27 90 59 63 26 40 26 72 36 

1

2

4

8
15 21 26 27 35 49 59 62 63 77 83 86 86 90 92 93 26 36 40 72
```

Then I tried to compile the same code setting the optimization option of gcc to O1, O2 or O3 and I got the result I was expecting:

```
83 86 77 15 93 35 86 92 49 21 62 27 90 59 63 26 40 26 72 36 

1

2

4

8

16
15 21 26 26 27 35 36 40 49 59 62 63 72 77 83 86 86 90 92 93
```

What is going on?

Comment: That is a typical indication of *undefined behavior*. Build with a sanitizer, `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and see what it tells you when running.

Comment: You have an access out of bounds on line 21 `while (i<mid) {
    temp[k++]=array[i++];
  }` https://godbolt.org/z/KTYP7qsxM

Comment: @giovanni106 Bad code as yours always has bugs. For example what is the magic number 20 used in functions?

Comment: OT: instead of using the magic number `20`, use `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` which is the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Sorry for  the magic number, I used it only in this piece of code for fast debugging purpose, but you're right, it's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in `mergeSort()` is that `i+j` could be greater than `size` resulting in `merge()` being called with an out-of-range `mid` value. For example, when `size` is 20, `j` is 8, and `i` is 16, the `mid` value `i+j` will be 24, which is greater than `size`. In `merge()`, the loop `while (i < mid) {` `temp[k++] = array[i]++;` `}` will copy elements with indices 16 to 23 inclusive, but indices 20 to 23 inclusive are outside the bounds of the arrays, leading to *undefined behavior*.

To correct the problem, note that it is only necessary to call `merge()` when the remaining unmerged portion is longer than the current current block size `j` (otherwise, the remaining unmerged portion has already been fully sorted). That is the case when `i+j<size`, which can only be the case when `j<size`. Therefore, change `for (j=1; j<=size; j*=2)` to `for (j=1; j<size; j*=2)`, and change `for (i=0; i<size; i+=2*j)` to `for (i=0; i+j<size; i+=2*j)`.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused by the compiler behavior and I forgot to check for `i+j<size`

Answer (score 2):

`int temp[size];` ... `j<=size;` means you can never access index `j` because it will be out of bounds during the last iteration.

Fix this by writing a non-obscure loop iterating from `j=0` to `j<size` and then modify the rest of the program accordingly.

There might be other bugs as well.